# iTunes account creation not allowed when trying to test In-App Purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I have an app in the App Store and I want to test in-app purchases. I followed the steps described on the [Apple website](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html) but I'm facing some problems.

When I try to log in in the iTunes in my application or in Settings/iTunes & App Stores, I receive the error:

> **iTunes account creation not allowed.**
>
> This Apple ID cannot be used with the iTunes Store at this time. Please try again later

I searched the internet but I found nothing about this. It seems like I am the first to encounter this kind of error.

[image: itunes account creation not allowed]

Comment: I just got this error too! Any ideas?

Comment: Are you testing on the Simulator or on an actual device?

Comment: You can see the gsm operator, then it's a real device, a iPhone 6S.

Comment: I ran into the same problem just a minute ago. Used to work 3 months ago when I was doing the same stuff. Apple might be testing something themselves, off to check on the developer forums ...

Answer (score 110):

Looks like Apple has this poorly documented. Basically, you shouldn't log in with your sandbox user from that screen. Log in when actually prompted by your test IAP.

Source: [Unable to log in with sandbox test users on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034491/unable-to-log-in-with-sandbox-test-users-on-device)

Comment: I have read already tried to log in from the app. I mentioned that in first post.

Comment: For me log in from the app works.  But from iTunes settings i get the mentioned issue.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. I fist though I had to log in in iCloud, but then I found out that iTunes Store and iCloud can have different accounts in settings, so I just logged out from iTunes Store to make it work.

Comment: But how can I then manage my Test-Purchases? I'd like to test the cancelation of an auto-renewing subscription...

Comment: Apple has everything poorly documented. This is how they write docs.

Answer (score 47):

I just had the same problem. Here's how I solved it:

1. Don't try to sign in Settings > iTunes & App Stores
2. Log out of iTunes & App Stores (make sure you're not logged into any account)
3. Just open the app you're trying to test
4. Your app will promt you to sign in
5. Enter your credentials for your sandbox test account

Et voilà! You're done. Worked for me. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Wow that is crazy!! I would never have thought of this. I truly believed that I couldn't log in "at this time" and was planning to "try again later"! How long later are they planning to let me log in? Its been saying this for 18 months so far, maybe if I wait 2 years? 3 years?

Comment: not working for me. Still keep asking the itunes account again and again

Comment: But how do I install the app? I'm trying to log in to testflight and I'm getting this f***** error.

Answer (score 7):

For those who are still facing an issue, here is the solution:
From settings main screen, select "iTunes & App Store", as seen in the picture

[image]

now scroll to bottom and you will find your previous apple is still there, sign out of that, see picture for reference, and now when doing in app purchase, it will ask for both apple id and password, use your sandbox tester apple id and password there.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This has changed... again. Here's how to fix it in 2020:

0) On your test device, go to Settings.

1) Click your account name at the the top, the one with "Apple ID, iCloud, iTunes & App Store" under it.

2) Click "iTunes & App Store"

3) Scroll all the way to the bottom and find the option: "SANDBOX ACCOUNT". It will have defaulted to your AppleID. Tap it and sign out.

4) Tap "Sign In" under SANDBOX ACCOUNT.

5) Add your Sand Box Account credentials. You will probably have to have verified your email address before this will work.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue. I tried `changing existing Sandbox tester account password` and tried to login on device...but didn't worked.

Even `iPhone device restart` didn't worked [last option that most developer follows ;-) ]

I thought it takes time to update this newly created Sandbox testing on DB. So `left the login option as it is on device`

Now, after launching app that contains In App purchase. Press on button that is responsible for In App purchase. This will prompt for Apple credentials. **Enter the Sandbox tester credentials here.**

Voila this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

The top answer is correct, but if you're still having the issue:

Make sure that the app you're trying to log into is a development app installed with Xcode. You'll get the same error if your version was installed from the App Store.

(I got confused because I have 5 versions of almost the same app.)