# In App Purchase sandbox - Invalid address

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have implemented In App Purchase in so many applications and tested all of them in Sandbox environment. Right now I am working on one of the app's In App Purchase, which i tested yesterday and was working fine, but by today morning none of the existing sandbox accounts working for In App test.

I followed one of the apple [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/70418) to solve issue but nothing seems to be working.In this thread so many developers faced same issue, some of them come with solution, but none of them works for me.

I have tried below solutions till now:

1. Add new product with all meta data and tried with new product Id.
2. Created fresh demo app to test In App Purchase with new certificates and profiles.But not working.
3. Created new sandbox tester, verify it from mail account.

I am able to fetch product info like Product name and price but not able to complete purchase. At first when OS ask to enter Apple ID and Password for Sandbox user I entered it, it accept credential and iTunes logged in with sandbox user.But then suddenly another OS alert prompt with `Invalid Address`.

Find below screen shot of that alert.[image]

When I tapped `Continue`, then it redirects to iTunes Store and after some loading, it display another alert with `iTunes account creation not allowed`. Below screen for that alert.

[image]

I have tried all possible solution but nothing worked for me. If any of you ever faced same problem then please update here.

Comment: review this link. may be it will help you..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034491/unable-to-log-in-with-sandbox-test-users-on-device

Comment: have you got any solution? we have facing the same issue by today itself.

Comment: Not yet, I tried everything. But if you will, please update here.

Comment: @AtulParmar: I tried sandbox account with App Store Territory as United States and United Kingdom and it works, but with Indian Accounts not working.

Comment: @technerd: I have only Indian Account, So how can i test it ?? Any idea?

Comment: @AtulParmar : You can create sandbox account with any country.

Comment: I also have faced the same issue, only for sandbox.
@AtulParmar  : Thank you so much your solution is works fine for me you are time saver men.

 But technerd is also right , what we have to do for Indian Account. anyone have idea?

Comment: @SudhirKotila : Please check my answer to create Sandbox account with any territory.

Comment: @AtulParmar:  Please check my answer to create Sandbox account with any territory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried sandbox account with App Store Territory as United States and United Kingdom and it works, but with Indian Accounts not working.

Follow below steps to create Sandbox Account:

1. Open itunesconnect.apple.com
2. Select `Users and Roles`
3. Select `Sandbox Testers`
4. Select `+` button
5. From App Store Territory , you can create Sandbox Account for any country and test In App Purchase

Select country as United States or United Kingdom, works for me.
[image]

Comment: Basically at present I was getting same issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758259/sandbox-user-login-invalid-address But I belong to India then also shall I require to select United States or United Kingdom ??

Comment: @Siddharth: You can create Sandbox account with any country and use in India for Sandbox testing.

Comment: @technerd The flow is anyway broken right ? You have to see pradeeps answer below to make it work.  You will get an error saying you will be redirected to US store, then it will be redirected, switch back to your app and do signin again, it will work. I am not able to signin and so subscription straight ahead.

Comment: @abhi1992 : agree with you , you have to switch store and login again but this is one time process.

Answer (score 2):

The "technerd" solution works properly in current situations, by using territory as "United States"
In case of Indian account, we need to follow the following extra steps.

1) After signin to iTunes Store message, we will get error in case of Indian Account. 
"This apple ID is only valid for purchases in the U.S. iTunes Store. You will be switched to that Store." Touch OK

2) This will take us to iTunes store link, and come back to same view.

3) Sign - in again.

4) Success message will appear as 
"You're currently subscribed to this. ..."

Hope this helps to persons like me.

Comment: This seems to be working for me as well.But this seems to be a hack. Is there any response from apple on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Apple server looks like inappropriate, Wait for some time & try again.

Answer (score 0):

Please logout with your sandbox account from your phone.Then make another account with App Store territory as United States, not as India.
I am sure it will works.
I am facing same problem ,as soon as i change Country ,it works like a charm.

Comment: This too is not working directly. We need to do what Pradeep mentioned in his post in this thread to make it work.