# Sandbox User Login - Invalid Address

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase

Basically I was trying to purchase subscription with developer mode certificates using Sandbox account details. Up to now I have used around 100 times same Sandbox user details and it was worked perfectly.

But from last 2 to 3 days its not get able to success in making purchase. At the end of purchase, I was getting following kind of dialog box then after no success in purchase.

Still application was not live in market so I can't use real apple account for making purchase so I was using sandbox user details for testing purpose.
Subscription as well normal product purchase also not working with same reason.

So what is running wrong in this? Please share some idea regarding this.

[image]

Comment: This might be the same issue you are having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672430/in-app-purchase-sandbox-invalid-address

Comment: But I belong to India and I have selected India in sandbox user. Also I have used same sandbox user details more than 100 times before. So now why should I require to change my account territory ?

Comment: getting same issue, i also tried more than 50 times not succeeded yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I found ad hoc solution at present.
I belong to India and up to now I used India country sandbox user account for testing purpose but from last few days its completely stopped working.

So I have created US sandbox user account and within Settings of iPhone, I selected US as country as Apple Store also selected as US user.

Then after I can able to test with sandbox user but still Indian user sandbox account not working so not sure what is going wrong into that but temporary solution I have so adjusted with that.

Comment: How did you select US as country of Apple Store? Since we are using sandbox test email ids, ai am not able to view apple id details in app store. How did you do that?

Comment: Within iTunes Connect, created new user which belong to any other country and then in iPhone's Settings section change with same country.