# Sign in with Apple - how to identify a user when sign up second time with real email

Tags: ios, macos, apple-sign-in, asauthorizationcontroller, sign-in-with-apple

I'm a bit of confused about [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationappleidcredential) and what's in the variable description in sign up with Apple. Let's say we have an scenario:

1. User `Sign in with Apple` using **fake/generated** email address.
2. User switching the devices or using different device with my app.
3. He's doing `Sign in with Apple` but with **real** email address.

[image]

#### Question: How to know that this is the same user in my database?

The docs linked above suggest that `user` in `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential` object is the answer I'm looking for:

> var user: String
>
> An identifier associated with the authenticated user.

But also Xcode displays this in variable description:

> /** @abstract An opaque user ID associated with the AppleID used for the sign in. This identifier will be stable across the 'developer team', it can later be used as an input to @see ASAuthorizationRequest to request user contact information.
>
> **The identifier will remain stable as long as the user is connected with the requesting client.  The value may change upon user disconnecting from the identity provider.**
>        */
>
> open var user: String { get }

What actualy that means in `Sign in with Apple` this `as long as the user is connected with the requesting client`. From that description I'm not sure if the user can deregister somehow or change this value or maybe this will happen in device-switch case?

#### What have I tried so far...

I've made a test in device and simulator and `user` value remain the same in dev environment but not sure how it's bahave IRL...

Comment: hey @Jakub https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034491/unable-to-log-in-with-sandbox-test-users-on-device user can't login iTunes with sandbox or generated user, I think first scenario will never come, it just a assumption. or if you find anything on this please update as a answer.

Comment: Hmmm, sorry, but that's really not relevant question/response from that link. What fake/generated address I have in mind was - `Hide my email` option in Sign in with apple. I added screenshot for clarification