# What is a "development-signed version" of an iOS app? How do I run a development-signed version of my app?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to test in-app purchases on an iOS device. At [Create a sandbox tester account](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev8b997bee1) it says:

> To connect to your development servers and the test environment for the App Store, run a development-signed version of your app and sign in using a sandbox tester account.

The problem is, I don't know what a "devepment-signed version" is, or how to run one.

In Xcode I have one app target, and under "Signing & Capabilities", "All", "Debug" and "Release" have "Automatically manage signing" checked. I cannot find a way to run a "development-signed" version and am not having luck figuring this out by Googling. Does this have to be a physical device, or can it be a simulator?

Comment: Do you have development servers? What’s the actual problem?

Comment: I'm trying to log in a sandbox user on a device in order to test IAP. I don't have a physical device with me right now and have been trying to use the simulator.

Comment: Well that’s the problem. You can’t do that. You can only do this on a device.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will wait until I have my device, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect a device to a mac, then build your app and send it down to that device, you are then running a development-signed version.  It can't be done on a simulator.

Comment: So if I connect a physical device and send the app to that device by running in Xcode, that app will be "developer-signed" and I will be able to log in a sandbox user on that device?

Comment: yes.  https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev60b6fbbc7 for more info

Comment: Yep, look like that did it. I used a physical device, and didn't have to do anything in Settings. When I tried to initiate an IAP, I got a gray pop-up for credentials, and I was able to use my sandbox user to sign in. So, when I run a developer-signed app, the sign-in user with always be bypassed in this way? Having signed in, I am now seeing the user as specified in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60135081/741970, but I was not able to sign in there in the first place. To sign in, I had to initiate a purchase from my app.

Comment: what if i want some of my non-developer testers to be able to test purchases in Testflight with multiple apple ids?

Comment: Apple has some good documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchases_in_xcode

Answer (score 0):

Feb 2024

Adding additional info, because I ended up here researching the same question.

From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchases_with_sandbox :

"Testing in-app purchases in the sandbox environment doesn’t require uploading your app binary to App Store Connect. You build and run your app from Xcode."

"In iOS and iPadOS, the sandbox account appears in Settings > App Store **after the first time you use the device to attempt a purchase in a development-signed app.** There’s no need to sign out of the non-Sandbox Apple ID."